# Does watch(provider) update children of parent widget?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm trying to update both Pages with one UserInteraction, therefore trying to access the same Stream in both Pages, with the Riverpod library.

Now to explain it further. When I pass the Stream to the `CustomerPage` I'm able to get the data (the String Anton). and when I click on the Button that triggers the change in FireStore, the String gets updated to "Marco" in the `ParentWidget`, when I go back to it. But it doesn't change in the `CustomerPage` unless I reopen the Page via the RaisedButton in the ParentWidget.
But I want **it to update after I click the Button on the CustomerPage**.

I hope this makes it clearer.

```
class ParentWidget extends ConsumerWidget{
Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch){
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> doc = watch(streamProvider.stream);
return Container(
child: Column(
  children: [ 
      Text(doc.name), //Lets say the name is Anton,
      RaisedButton(
         child: Text(" road to CustomerPage"),
         onPressed:(){
             Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RouteGenerator.customerPage, arguments: doc);
     },), //RaisedButton
   ],), //Column
   );  //Container
  }
 }

class CustomerPage extends StatelessWidget{
   Stream<DocumentSnapshot> docStream
   CustomerPage({this.docStream});
   Widget build(BuildContext context){
   return Column(
        children: [ 
          Text(docStream.name) //Here is also Anton
          RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Change Name"),
              onPressed: () {
                  context.read(streamProvider).changeName("Marco"); 
            },), //RaisedButton
         ]
       ); //Column
      }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a code example to help demonstrate what you're trying to accomplish? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AlexHartford I've added the code down below. Pls let me know if this is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On how I've understood so far is that, riverpod allows you to fetch the state of a provider, which basically is a value(?), that's why it's sufficient to just watch it in any Widget you want to access it's data from. There is no need anymore (just speaking for my case), to let Widgets pass the around in the App.

Down below is the solution which i believe to be right.

It also doesn't matter on how many times I call the provider. It's always going to be same Instance. For my case it means, that doc and doc2 are the same.
I hope this makes it clearer.

```
class ParentWidget extends ConsumerWidget{
Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch){
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> doc = watch(streamProvider.stream);
return Container(
child: Column(
  children: [ 
      Text(doc.name), //Lets say the name is Anton,
      RaisedButton(
         child: Text(" road to CustomerPage"),
         onPressed:(){
             Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RouteGenerator.customerPage);
     },), //RaisedButton
   ],), //Column
   );  //Container
  }
 }

class CustomerPage extends ConsumerWidget{
Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch){
 Stream<DocumentSnapshot> doc2 = watch(streamProvider.stream);
   return Column(
        children: [ 
          Text(doc2.name) //Here is also Anton
          RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Change Name"),
              onPressed: () {
                  context.read(streamProvider).changeName("Marco"); 
            },), //RaisedButton
         ]
       ); //Column
      }
}
```

Comment: Don't pass around the stream, just watch it the same way you are in the ParentWidget. There's no need to pass providers/provided values around like that when they are accessible globally.

Comment: Does it make a difference in total read counts in firebase? I somehow can't fully grasp the idea of riverpod. I'm able to make it run on my code but I just don't understand the dataflows. Lets say Provider A is providing the Stream<Doc> via watch(provider) to ParentWidget. If i call watch(provider) in the CustomerWidget am I watching Provider A or a different Provider B? @AlexHartford

Comment: No. When you create a provider, you're only creating it once in the global scope. Every time you read it from another file isn't actually recomputing the provider, it's just giving you the current value.

Comment: Wow quick to reply haha I've edited it, but you've already answered my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to, we can salvage this post into a useful resource if you edit your question, adding additional notes and your code example from this answer, then delete this answer as it's not really an answer. One of us could then provide a real answer to the question.

Comment: I've just done it. Can you check if it's correct? But I hope it should be :D.

Comment: LGTM, go ahead and accept it. I might make a few edits but nothing major. Good job!

Comment: While in lockdown I started to create an App that I want to use in production. And I've basically started from scratch without any knowledge. 
I just wanted to ask if there is any way, I could ask you a couple of questions based on riverpod, just for understanding. Mainly on StateNotifierProvider. 
If yes let me know. 
If not, thank you anyways you really helped me a lot man.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231534/discussion-between-alex-hartford-and-theundercoverartist).